# Creating a setup for windows application by excluding app.exe.config file in .Net

Tags: .net, web-services

I get a issue while deploying my setup the issue is:

I hosted a web service and i have created a reference to that service in my windows application. As usual, the service behaviours, and the endpoints listening to that service is configured in app.config file. while creating setup for my application the app.exe.config is getting included with the setup and gets deployed into the installed machine. so the user can modify that app.config.exe file. By excluding the app.exe.config file via ExcludeFilter property i couldn't get connected to my service. so its throwing a error.

How could i resolve this issue by hiding or excluding my app.config.exe file in the installing machine?

Comment: Why do you want to exclude the config file? The service endpoint *shouldn't* need to be a secret (and there's no way to keep it so from a determined user)

Comment: In my config file, normally i have my service referred, its behaviour and endpoints and as well as in appsettings i have added a key which contains the URL of that service hosted which is used for checking the service connectivity from my application. So, if suppose my user opens & edits or do somechanges in the MyApplication.exe.config file then my user will not get connected to the service at all. Atlast my application wont function well. is there any solution to overcome from this?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at using [Windows Installer XML (WIX)](http://wix.sourceforge.net/index.html) to build your setup application - that way you could gather the correct configuration for the endpoints from the user carrying out the installation and modyfy the configuration during the installaiton process

Alternativly you might like to take a look at this [blog post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx) showing how the new web config transformation syntax could be used as part of building your setup